# Custom SharedPreferences class

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android and learning. I have theme changing option in my application from where the user can switch themes. I was using a global variable for saving theme number in the app but it was getting a loss when application get cleared from the background. So I have thought for use SharedPreferences for this purpose. I have found one simple and easy way to store and retrieve SharedPreference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058089/8387050).

**My code is like below** :

```
public class Keystore {
    private static Keystore store;
    private SharedPreferences SP;
    private static String filename="Keys";
    public static int theme=1;

    private Keystore(Context context) {
        SP = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    }

    public static Keystore getInstance(Context context) {
        if (store == null) {
            store = new Keystore(context);
        }
        return store;
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = SP.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return SP.getString(key, null);
    }

    public int getInt(String key) {
        return SP.getInt(key, 0);
    }

    public void putInt(String key, int num) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = SP.edit();

        editor.putInt(key, num);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void clear(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = SP.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void remove(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = SP.edit();

        editor.remove(filename);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

And as per example given in original answer, I am trying to use it in my activity class like below for getting value

```
int theme= store.getInt("theme");
Log.d(getClass().getName(),"theme"+theme);
```

But it's returning 0 instead of 1. I have also doubt that I have saved default value as 1 in that class like `public static int theme=1;` This is the correct way for saving default value in SharedPreferences?

Thanks

Comment: where did you saved value in shared preferences ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I have used it like public static int theme=1; for default and not committed any save till now.

Comment: if you haven't saved any value then what are you fetching from shared preferences ? It will always return default value of integer i.e. 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**`commit ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
>   SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the
>   requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   SharedPreferences.

```
public void putInt(String key, int num) 
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = SP.edit();

        editor.remove("key");
        editor.putString("key", num);
        editor.commit(); // IF commit() showing warning then use apply() instead .
        editor.apply();

    }
```

**NOTE**

> If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from
>   your application's main thread, consider using apply() instead.

Comment: commit use to give warning now. It is recommended to use apply instead

Comment: @VivekMishra indeed .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch by default 1 value when you when you don't save data in sharepreferance then you have to change in in your method like

```
public int getInt(String key) {
    return SP.getInt(key, 1);
}
```

It will work for you.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for nice suggestion. I have one more question. In Example class its used SP = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(filename,0); like this. What if I want multiple key to store

Comment: For take more information about sharepreferance please see link : https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: If you like my answer then please accept it and upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first save value in shared preferences so that you can retrieve it later. To save it use the below code

```
store.putInt(your int value);
```

and retrieve it from shared preference same like you are doing

```
int theme= store.getInt("theme");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
private void saveTheme()
{
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("filename here", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("theme", 1);
editor.commit();
} 



private int getTheme()
{
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("filename here", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedpreferences.getInt("theme",0);
}
```

You can add them in Utility class or make a seperate PreferenceHelper class and make sharedPreference global.

Hope it Helps !!